# Why do I get a "will always yield true" warning when translating the following from Java to Scala?

Tags: java, sql, scala

Below is a fairly standard piece of Java code which has been translated to Scala

```
 val result: ResultSet = statement.executeQuery(query)

  while (result.next) {
    if (result.getDouble("FIELD") != null) {

    }
 }
```

Why do I get

> warning: comparing values of types Double and Null using `!=' will
>   always yield true?

Comment: Try writing `(result.getDouble("FIELD") : java.lang.Double) != null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, it's because a Double in scala can never be Null.

Trying something simple out in the console came up with errors:

```
scala> val d:Double = null
<console>:13: error: type mismatch;
found   : Null(null)
required: Double
```

On the other hand, a `java.lang.Double` *can* be null:

```
scala> val d:java.lang.Double = null
d: java.lang.Double = null
```

So your double is probably a Scala `Double` as opposed to a Java `Double`

*EDIT* I poked around a bit, and it looks like using java.sql.ResultSet's `getDouble` method will return a scala `Double` object, which accounts for the warning. As for an alternative to checking for `null`, I'm not sure that was ever an option. In Java, the method returned a primitive `double`, which would default to `0.0`. I may be wrong, but I don't think Java primitives could ever be `null`.

*Edit2* Removed some stuff that was more speculation than answer.

Comment: So how would I do the equivalent test in Scala?  The standard seems to be pattern matching but I can't see how to apply that here

Comment: It will depend on the return type of the `getDouble` method. If it returns an `Option[Double]` then you can test it for `None` (as opposed to `Some(value)`)

Comment: I added a bit to my answer- should be a bit more helpful to you now.

Comment: Just to clarify: a Java API that can return `null` will never magically start returning `Option[...]` when used from Scala. I interpreted your first paragraph as implying that, but I may very well be reading it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The question is more about java.sql than about scala. getDouble returns a double(java) or Double(Scala) which cannot be null. You must call [wasNull](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#wasNull%28%29) after having called getDouble (or others similar) to check whether the field was null, in which case the value returned by getDouble must be ignored. Depending on the driver, you might have to do that even for strings field, even if a string may be null. getString could well return an empty string rather than a null for a null field.